# Check the name of the last sheet in my workbook and if it has a certain name then break the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a code for error handling that checks the name of the last sheet and if the sheet has a certain name then it should break the rest of my code.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
MsgBox ws.Index '& "-" & ws.Name & "-" & ws.CodeName
```

Here it copies a sheet from another workbook into ThisWorkbook in the end. My last sheet at the moment is called "Legend".

```
Sheets(Sheet1).COPY After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

Here I want it to say that if the last sheet is "Legend" it means that sheet is wrong and the sheet was not copied so break the code.

```
If ws.Name Like "*Legend*" Then Exit Sub
```

But it is not working properly as it break the code anyway regardless if the copy pasting of the sheet was successful. Any suggestions??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you redefining `ws` after the sheet has been copied? If not `ws` has been set as the `Legend` sheet. Reset `ws` just before your `IF`, alternatively just use `If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name Like "*Legend*" Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Yes exactly that was my mistake. Thanks a lot! Super helpful ur comment i could not see it for some reason

Answer (score 4):

You are most likely setting `ws` before the extra sheet is copied, so it doesn't matter how many sheets you add, `ws` will always be `Legend`.

Try either:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
If ws.Name Like "*Legend*" Then Exit Sub
```

Which will recount the number of sheets inclusive of any you have copied.

Or if you need `ws` to stay as `Legend` for later use:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Name Like "*Legend*" Then Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code as I understand it:-

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
MsgBox ws.Index '& "-" & ws.Name & "-" & ws.CodeName
Sheets(Sheet1).COPY After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
If ws.Name Like "*Legend*" Then Exit Sub
```

Obviously, you copy the sheet from the other workbook before you ask whether you should copy it. Therefore the copy process can't be stopped by examining the name of the last sheet. The copy has already been made. If you want to stop the copying, ask the question before.

However, the above code will not do anything to the newly copied sheet if the sheet which was last before the new sheet was added is named 'Legend'. The name of the new sheet is not being examined.

Comment: From the OP's question I understand they don't want to ask if they **should** copy the new sheet in, but whether or not the copy was **successful**, in which case their ordering is correct.